# MySQL infinite loop in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

The following query probably results an infinite loop:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT 
            t2.`value`
        FROM
            `table` t2
        WHERE
            t2.`variable` = 'xxx'
                AND t2.`read` = (SELECT 
                    MAX(t1.`read`)
                FROM
                    `table` t1
                WHERE
                    t1.`variable` = 'xxx'
                        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.`read`) < (1401801648 - n.integers)
                )
    )
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @N:=@N + 1 AS integers
    FROM
        mysql.help_relation, (SELECT @N:=0) dum
    LIMIT 48) n
```

I need a result with 48 rows for 48 different time ranges (In this example `1401801648` minus `{1..48}`). Each row should contain a value depending on the current time range. The query on the bottom is for these 48 ranges. 
The query in the middle is needed to find the date for the newest entry which is older than the calculated timestamp `(1401801648 - n.integers)`. The upper query tells me the value of the row with the date from the query in the middle.

When the "n.integers" is replaced by a number everything works fine.

Without the subquery (t2) the query is not in a loop(?):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(t1.`read`)
        FROM
            `table` t1
        WHERE
            t1.`variable` = 'xxx'
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.`read`) < (1401801648 - n.integers)
    )
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @N:=@N + 1 AS integers
    FROM
        mysql.help_relation, (SELECT @N:=0) dum
    LIMIT 48) AS n
```

Comment: No. What makes you think so? There's no "loop" at all in this query. The query will not yield any result, as your `1401801648` is already a unix_timestamp, so this will become `0` and your `unix_timestamp(t1.read)` is most probably not smaller than `0`. Also the whole query seems to be a little "misguided". Maybe you should rather tell us, what you want to do and we might come up with a better query.

Comment: @fancyPants: Thanks for your answer. I have described the problem more in detail below the code example.

Comment: What does it do when it not "works fine"? Any error messages?

Comment: The query returns the last entry outside the given range when the `n.integers` is replaced by a number.

Comment: Your SQL is missing a bracket. There is no closing bracket for the sub query n the SELECT. Also, if your timestamps that you check are only 1 second apart then it seems likely that you will have many values of n.integers where the latest row is the same one, or that you have many repeated timestamps in which case your sub query will return more than one row.

Comment: @Kickstart: MySQL returns no error. The query has no missing bracket (you mean one bracket right?). The query is running endless. In the original request the n.integer will be multiplied with 1800 seconds, but for the problem it is not relevant.

Comment: Your first bit of sql does have a bracket missing (there is no matching one for the first bracket). However can you post your table declares and a bit of sample data. If the value of t1.read is not unique for a value of t1.variable then your sub query will bring back more than one row which should cause an error.

Comment: @Kickstart: You're right, we've added the missing bracket (was just a copy & paste fault). `t1.read` is unique.

Comment: I can't see an issue without table declares / test data to check against. However it might be possible to bring the same data back with `SELECT 
    *,
    (
  SELECT t2.value
        FROM table t2
        WHERE t2.variable = 'xxx'
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.read) < (1401801648 - n.integers)
  ORDER BY t1.read
  LIMIT 1
 )
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @N:=@N + 1 AS integers
    FROM
        mysql.help_relation, (SELECT @N:=0) dum
    LIMIT 48) n` . Don't think this is a good idea for a live query but at least might help with debugging. Getting1000+ rows from help_relation to ignore most won't help

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method avoiding using variables:-

```
SELECT sub1.a_cnt, t2.value
FROM table t2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sub1.a_timestamp, sub1.a_cnt, t1.variable, MAX(t1.read) AS max_timestamp
    FROM
    (
        SELECT (1401801648 - units.i + 10 * tens.i) AS a_cnt,(1401801648 - units.i + 10 * tens.i) AS a_timestamp
        FROM
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
        WHERE units.i + 10 * tens.i BETWEEN 1 AND 48
    ) sub1
    INNER JOIN table t1
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.read) < sub1.a_timestamp
    WHERE t1.variable = 'xxx'
    GROUP BY sub1.a_timestamp
) sub2
ON t2.read = sub2.max_timestamp
AND t2.variable = sub2.variable
```

This uses a load of unioned queries getting constants to generate the numbers 0 to 9, cross joins that against another copy of itself and does a minor calulation to get all the numbers from 0 to 99, with a WHERE clause to narrow it down to the range 1 to 48, and uses this to calculate the timestamps required.

This is then joined against your table to get the max read date for each timestamp / generated number.

The results of this are then joined back against your table to get the other details from that row (in this case your value column).

Not tested it but hopefully it gives you an idea.